# Google Place API returns incorrect / inconsistent result for subpremises

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Place API to validate addresses and noticed some interesting behavior when querying sub-premise (e.g. unit) addresses.

Observations:

1. [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=AIzaSyAiTC0wk8xIgLW2NstpE-lOeVuuFFwlaNo&query=3/7 Murray St, Nuriootpa SA 5355, Australia](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=AIzaSyAiTC0wk8xIgLW2NstpE-lOeVuuFFwlaNo&query=3/7%20Murray%20St,%20Nuriootpa%20SA%205355,%20Australia) returns two results, **3/7 Murray St** and **7/3 Murray St**.
2. Removing the ending ', Australia' from the query string, [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=AIzaSyAiTC0wk8xIgLW2NstpE-lOeVuuFFwlaNo&query=3/7 Murray St, Nuriootpa SA 5355](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=AIzaSyAiTC0wk8xIgLW2NstpE-lOeVuuFFwlaNo&query=3/7%20Murray%20St,%20Nuriootpa%20SA%205355) returns only one result **7/3 Murray St** which actually is the wrong one!

Actually I'm using the first URL and let user to choose one if multiple returned. But users complained that there is no point to show them the 'reversed' address if the correct one is found. I did a bit more testing and found that Google return single result if query string does not contain 'Australia' (2nd URL). Unfortunately the single result was wrong in this case.

The problematic addresses I've found so far are:

- 3/7 Murray St, Nuriootpa SA 5355
- 6/28 Ann St. Nambour QLD 4560

Is there any workaround (e.g. by pre-format / pre-processing the query string) to let Google Place API return the only correct address? Thanks in advance!